# What is the best natural source of Vitamin D (excluding sun)?

Tags: vitamin-d

I wonder if there is a top natural source of `Vitamin D` excluding sitting under the sun to get a good value in RDI or DV?

From what I could google, the percentage of Vitamin D in fatty fish is too small to count, and in winter there is little to no sun. I suppose then the only source would be supplements?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory ive done heaps of research on google, but there isnt any true source of vitamin D that could full the 100% of RDV. Thats why I asked a simple question here.

Comment: State your research sources, please, and please add details to what RDI, DV and RDV are. As a starting point, there are other nutrient sources for vitamin D, besides fish and supplements.

Answer (score 1):

> The two major forms [of vitamin D] are vitamin D2 and vitamin D3. Vitamin D2 (ergocalciferol) is largely human-made and added to foods, whereas vitamin D3 (cholecalciferol) is synthesized in the skin of humans from 7-dehydrocholesterol and is also consumed in the diet via the intake of animal-based foods. [...]  The differences do not affect metabolism (i.e., activation), and both forms function as prohormones. When activated, the D2 and D3 forms have been reported to exhibit identical responses in the body [DRI - Institute of Medicine of the National Academies](https://www.nap.edu/read/13050/chapter/5)

with that being said, in the same text we can find that

> There are a few naturally occurring food sources of vitamin D. These include fatty fish [such as salmon, tuna, and mackerel], fish liver oil, and egg yolk. Some foods are, however, fortified with vitamin D.

for example in the United States, fluid milk is voluntarily fortified with 400 IU per quart

The Food and Nutition Board has established the Recommended Dietary Allowances (RDA) to make nutrient recommendations [Dietary Reference Intakes (DRIs)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK56068/table/summarytables.t2/?report=objectonly)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks :)
So the percentage of Vitamin D in fatty fish is too small, and in winter there is no sun.. I suppose then the only source would be supplements?